# Staged rollout: Can people still go into google playstore to download the new version?

Tags: android, google-play, release, rollout

I am curious if its possible for the user to download the new version of the app while its rolling out.
Like: A user who are not part of the rollout, still are able to download the latest (new) version if he/she goes into google play.

I have heard its like that for iOS, but not sure if its possible for users to do it in android.

Comment: My impression from previous rollouts has been that it isn't possible for a user to force an update. That is, they'll have to wait until they get included the in percentage of the users that will get the new version.

Comment: aahhh oki thank you :)